# Can somebody explain the eclipse.p2.profile

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, p2

I'm organizing a build of an Eclipse RCP.

Using the `p2-director`, one property is the `profile`. The Eclipse [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/p2_director.html) only states the below explanation, which isn't that clear in my view.

> -profile: the profile id containing the description of the targeted product. This ID is is defined by the eclipse.p2.profile property
>   contained in the config.ini of the targeted product. For the Eclipse
>   SDK the ID is "SDKProfile"

So my question is this:

What is the profile used for, what does it describes and how can I ensure I use it properly?

Does anybody have a better explanation or a link to a proper documentation?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert, but I will try. It basically contains all of the p2 stuff required to make the software update mechanism work for your application. You will need this with an RCP application. It contains (among other things) the list of artifacts that are currently installed. It allows you to revert to a former installation state.

You can find the examples of this in any Eclipse installation in `p2//org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry`

Comment: In addition, you need to have a profile, but in theory you can call your RCP app profile something different than `SDKProfile`, although within one RCP app it won't hurt to call it that.

Answer (score 2):

Since P2 installs things, it has to have a database of the installation state. P2 can maintain multiple installation states. Each database P2 has to maintain is called a profile. A profile is accessed using an identifier. When running, P2 has a registry of these databases.

There are two properties that P2 receives from the `config.ini` when it starts up as part of an Eclipse RCP: `eclipse.p2.data.area` - Where to physically store its data - and `eclipse.p2.profile` - What key to use for the installation state of the installation you are running in.

Comment: Best explanation on the internet